# Wrong credential when connecting to Remote Desktop

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I have been working on this issue for the past week without any success. 
Here's what's happening, I use Global SonicWall to VPN in, then I go through our internal firewall. Everything works perfectly until there, but then when I want to remote desktop to our Windows Server 2012 R2, I get the login window where it says "Wrong Credentials". 
I know they are the correct credentials, as I can use my colleague's laptop and I am able to connect fine to the server. 
Something must be wrong with my laptop, it is a Latitude E5470 Dell. Could it have to do with my Network Driver?

Thank you for your help. 
-Clemmy

Comment: Could could you please be a bit more specific? You VPN in to which computer/server/network? From the VPN endpoint you then go through your firewall. How do you achieve that? Is it another VPN hop or do you RDP into a server/client? How is the layout of your network? What is in the DMZ, what not? You don't have to supply your exact ip addresses or host names, but if you help the community with more details the community will be able to support you in your efforts to resolve your problem and find the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the credentials prompt, make sure what you are typing is what you are meaning to type, caps lock on of off, num lock, etc.

Also, are you prefixing it with your domain? test-domain.local\adminaccount? If its not a domain, have you tried .\adminaccount?